# WPF databinding to a linked list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, linked-list, datasource

I want to databind a ListBox to a linked list

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyText{ get; set; }
    public MyClass PreviousItem{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to use an instance of MyClass as the datasource of a ListBox, to basically show a list of the MyClass instance and all it's PreviousItems.

Of course binding to an instance of MyClass will result in only the topmost parent being shown. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need a custom implementation of a LinkedList in the first place? There is a .NET implementation already: System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList

Other than that, you have basically three options:

1. Recommended: If it fits your
   business logic, impement at least
   IEnumerable in MyClass (like the .NET lists)
2. Create a ViewModel which traverses
   your items of MyClass and
   puts them into an
   ObservableCollection
3. Create an IValueConverter object to
   convert your linked list to a
       collectionType like
       ObservableCollection

Comment: Whoops I missed the Generic LinkedList, that's exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BCL `LinkedList<T>` class. Or alternatively if you like your class very much you can implement `IEnumerable` like this

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<MyClass>
    {
        public string MyText { get; set; }
        public MyClass PreviousItem { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var item = this;
            do
            {
                yield return item;
                item = item.PreviousItem;
            } while (item != null);

        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually implementing IEnumerable would suffice:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> TraverseItemsFromCurrent
    {
        get
        {
            var current = this;
            yield return current;
            while (current.PreviousItem != null)
            {
                current = current.PreviousItem;
                yield return current;
            }
        }
    }
```

And yes, using `LinkedList<T>` might be easier and more adequate to your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing (in my opinion) is to implement IEnumerable

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }
    public MyClass PreviousItem { get; set; }

    IEnumerator<MyClass> IEnumerable<MyClass>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (var item = this; item.PreviousItem != null; item = item.PreviousItem)
            yield return item;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<MyClass>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you code would look like this

```
public Window1()
    {
        MyClass item1 = new MyClass() {MyText = "No1"};
        MyClass item2 = new MyClass() {MyText = "No2"};
        MyClass item3 = new MyClass() {MyText = "No3"};
        MyClass item4 = new MyClass() {MyText = "No4"};

        item4.PreviousItem = item3;
        item3.PreviousItem = item2;
        item2.PreviousItem = item1;

        DataContext = item4; // your first item
    }
```